# MySQL: Concat all columns

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

for example we have a table with the columns "id", "name", "type", "year".
My target output would be `SELECT CONCAT(id, name, type, year) FROM table`.

Is it possible to do this without knowing the columns, so I can use it with every table I want without analysing its columns first? Something like `CONCAT(*)`?

I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Regards
Wulf

Comment: It is not possible. The fileld names have to be known. But you can output data into the CSV file without field separator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you first have to know the columns. This

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table
```

will return all columns. Use the result to make your `SELECT` query.

Comment: Too bad that there is no `*` way, but thanks anyway! This is how I'm doing it already.

Answer (score 2):

Check the information_schema table of MySQL, it contains meta-information concerning your tables.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html